# How do you find the range of $f(x)=\frac{x+3}{|x-2|}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

I know how to find the **Range** when the **Modulus/ Absolute-Value** function is in the Numerator.
But how do I solve it when a modulus function is in the denominator?
Can you please explain it  with this example:
$$f(x)= \frac{x+3}{|x-2|}$$

When $x>2$, $$f(x)= \frac{x+3}{x-2},$$ whose range is $\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$. When $x<2$, $$f(x)= \frac{x+3}{-x+2},$$ whose range is $\mathbb{R}-\{-1\}$. So the Final Range set should be $\mathbb{R} - \{-1,1\}$. But plotting the function in Desmos Graph Shows that Range is $(-1, \infty)$. That's where I'm getting confused.

Comment: Well.. you can rewrite your function as $f(x)=(x+3)|x-2|/(x-2)^2$ which does not have absolute value in the denominator, and you say you know how to deal with those.

Comment: Consider the cases $x >2$ and $x < 2$ separately.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @EthanBolker.  That is, I see no reason to try to force yourself into looking for some elegant approach.  The expression $|x-2|$ clearly has two distinct evaluations, depending on whether $x \geq 2$ or $x < 2.$  Further, the original function is clearly undefined when $x=2$.  This implies that the domain of the original function does not include the value $x=2$.

Comment: @EthanBolker I had already used this approach. When **x>2**, f(x)=(x+3)/(x-2), whose range is **R**-{1}. When **x<2**, f(x)=(x+3)/(-x+2), whose range is **R**-{-1}. So the Final Range set should be **R**-{-1,1}. But plotting the function in **Desmos Graph** Shows that Range is (-1,∞). That's where I'm getting confused.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  If you explained how you obtained those ranges, it would make it easier for readers to detect any errors you may have made.  When you post a question here, your attempt should be included in the question.

Comment: If you know how to find the range of $\frac{|x-2|}{x+3}$, you can invert this range to get the range for your function.

Comment: You can’t use the entire range of your functions, your domain is restricted by the values of $x$.  You need to compute the range of your two fractions over your specified domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $$f(x)= \frac{x+3}{|x-2|}$$
>
> When $x\ge2$, $$g(x)= \frac{x+3}{x-2},$$ whose range is $\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$.

Yes, but what you want is not $g$ but its restriction $g|_{[2,\infty)},$ which has range $(1,\infty).$

> When $x<2$, $$h(x)= \frac{x+3}{-x+2},$$ whose range is $\mathbb{R}-\{-1\}$.

Similarly, you want $h|_{(-\infty,2)},$ which has range $(-1,\infty).$

> But plotting the function in Desmos Graph Shows that Range is $(-1, \infty).$

Yes, this is the union of the two ranges above.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that Solution.